# Suppressing Java function to print to console in R

Tags: java, r, text, console, rstudio

I use a function called `R2BGLiMS` that is a front-end to a Java application.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("pjnewcombe/R2BGLiMS") # see https://github.com/pjnewcombe/R2BGLiMS
```

My problem is that this function prints a lot of output to console which I want to suppress. I tried all of `sink`, `invisible`, `suppressMessages` and `capture.output`. The part of the function which is created by `cut` or `paste` can be suppressed in this way (e.g. `sink` to file). However there is a bulk of text that is still printed to console.

Is there a way to suppress all of the text?

Here a reproducible example, which is taken from Example 1 in `?R2BGLiMS`.

```
# Run Example 1
utils::data(biopsy, package = "MASS") # Example logistic dataset
covariate.names <- paste0("V",c(1:9))
# Recommend standardising predictors to justify default common hierarchical prior on effects
for (v in covariate.names) {biopsy[,v] <- scale(biopsy[,v])} 
biopsy$class <- as.integer(biopsy$class) - 1
biopsyResults <- R2BGLiMS( # Takes a few minutes to run
  likelihood="Logistic",
  data=biopsy,
  outcome.var="class",
  model.space.priors=list("a"=1, "b"=length(covariate.names), "Variables"=covariate.names), # Beta-binomial(1,P) model space prior
  extra.arguments=list("AlphaPriorMu"=log(mean(biopsy$class)/(1-mean(biopsy$class)))) # Recommend centering intercept prior on logit(event rate)
)
```

Comment: Ideally, you need to contact developer and convince him to use something else for logging, such as `java.util.logging.Logger`, for instance. Starting from there, it should be trivial.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov so it's not possible to use `R` to suppress all messages?

Comment: I'm not saying it is or not, I only suggested that there should be non-hacky way to suppress these messages. Looking at Git link you've attached, some of those messages also look pretty important to simply skip suppressing. This can be addressed as well with logging at different priorities.